# Unknown problem compiling/rendering with React Hooks/Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've developed a website with React where I'm fetching data from a JSON file inside a Context component:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const LanguageContext = createContext(undefined)

export const LanguageProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('ES');

    const updateLanguage = e => setLanguage(e.target.value)

    const [text, setText] = useState({}); 

    useEffect(() => { 
        fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julenclarke/ejtos-react_budget_app/main/languagesdata.json`) 
          .then((response) => response.json()) 
          .then((jsonData) => setText(jsonData))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error)); 
      }, []); 

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider
            value={{
                language,
                updateLanguage: updateLanguage,
                text
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useLanguage = () => useContext(LanguageContext);
```

And then I call to that data from another component:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useLanguage } from './LanguageContext';

function Header() {
    const { language, updateLanguage, text } = useLanguage();

    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="header-logo">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-item">
                <img width={300} src={require("../assets/img/julenclarkelogo.png")} alt="Julen Clarke logo" />
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="header-links">
                {/* <!-- divs in reverse order because of flex-direction: row-reverse; --> */}
                 <div className="language-picker">
                    <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 40 }}>
                        <Select
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
                            id="demo-simple-select-standard"
                            value={language}
                            onChange={updateLanguage}
                            label="ES"
                        >
                            <MenuItem value={'ES'}>ES</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'EU'}>EU</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'EN'}>EN</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </div> 
                <div className="header-nav-list">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/videos" className="nav-item">{text[language].videos}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/photos" className="nav-item">{text[language].photos}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/cv" className="nav-item">{text[language].cv}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/press" className="nav-item">{text[language].press}</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/contact" className="nav-item">{text[language].contact}</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Where depending on the value of the language I extract a different piece of data from the JSON file already mentioned:

```
{
    "EU": {
        "videos": "Bideoak",
        "photos": "Argazkiak"
    },
    "ES": {
        "videos": "Vídeos",
        "photos": "Fotos"
    },
    "EN": {
        "videos": "Videos",
        "photos": "Photos"
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following error when compiling:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videos')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videos')
    at Header (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2800:40)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48914:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52200:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53496:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38506:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38550:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38607:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58481:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57728:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57651:9)
```

I don't know why it says 'videos' is undefined because if I make the changes after compiling it kind of works the way I want, so I suspect it might have to do something with the rendering. However, the compilation error description is referring to compilation files to which I'm not familiar at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the **text** state variable is set as an empty object, which means that on the initial render of the application, your LanguageContext provider will pass down an empty object to its children.

The data from the api will be fetched simultaneously, however on the first render your **text** state variable will always be an empty object.

This assumes that your logic is fine, but you need to conditionally render your header navigation list as shown below:

```js
<div className="header-nav-list">
  {text[language] ? (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/videos" className="nav-item">
          {text[language].videos}
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/photos" className="nav-item">
          {text[language].photos}
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/cv" className="nav-item">
          {text[language].cv}
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/press" className="nav-item">
          {text[language].press}
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/contact" className="nav-item">
          {text[language].contact}
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  ) : (
    <div>No data available</div>
  )}
</div>;
```

Comment: Even though it compiles with your solution, it isn't the solution I'm looking for. Isn't there a way in which **text** is initialised with the data I'm fetching from the JSON?

Comment: One solution would be to import the json object directly to your component file and initialise your text state with it. Take a look at this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader, it will assist you to import information from your json files directly to your jsx/tsx files.